# Doing reverse of a number in C language

Tags: c, reverse

While doing reverse program in C,I am getting issue with number 01 & 10 because its reverse is not showing in the output. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int i,n,rev=0;
   printf("Enter the number:");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   while(n>0){
      i=n%10;
      rev=rev*10+i;
      n=n/10;
   }
   printf("Reverse of that number:%d",rev);
   return 0;
}
```

I am expecting that if I give `01` as input, its reverse must be shown as `10`.

Comment: do you have to use `int` type? Far easier to do this with a string.

Comment: Why do you think the *value* of `01` will be any different from `1`, or from `00001`?

Comment: You need to take into account input string size

Comment: You cannot do this with integers if you need to care about leading or trailing zeros. Either avoid such numbers or use strings.

Comment: If you don't need to actually store the reversed number in your program, just write the digits to `stdout` as you calculate them.

Comment: Did the instructor who assigned this exercise say that the reverse of `01` should be `10`, or vice versa?  If yes, then they were implicitly telling you, "Use strings to manipulate these numbers, not `int`."  But if not, I'd say, just don't worry about it.  (Reversing the digits of a number is a completely artificial exercise anyway, with no practical value.)

Comment: @Gerhardh [cannot do this with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75451453/doing-reverse-of-a-number-in-c-language/75453438#comment133127514_75451453), there are non-string [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75453438/2410359).

Comment: when `01` is the input, the while-loop would run only once for the **n=n/10=1/10=0** fails `while(n>0)`, then the `rev` would be `1` not `10`.

Answer (score 1):

If obliged to still use `"%d"`:

Detect the input offset with `"%n"`, which stores the character offset of the scan at that point.

```
   int offset1 = 0;
   int offset2 = 0;
   if (scanf(" %n%d%n", &offset1, &n, &offset2) == 1) {
     while (offset1 < offset2) {
      offset1++;
      i = n%10;
      rev = rev*10+i;
      n = n/10;
   }
```

`offset2 - offset1` will be the character count of the number and input `"01"` has a character count of 2.

This still gets fooled if the text input includes a sign character.  Additional, and not so clear, code needed to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, this is trivial if approached from a string perspective.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char input[100] = {0};

  if (scanf("%99s", input) != 1) {
    printf("Invalid input.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  size_t len = strlen(input);

  char *output = malloc(len + 1);

  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    output[i] = input[len-i-1];
  }
  output[i] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", output);

  free(output);

  return 0;
}
```

You could add in validation code that determines that the input actually is a valid integer, and if you actually need an int back, there are library functions like `strtol` that will accomplish this.